# How to change the rows or columns of a grid without messing up the content

Tags: javascript, grid, p5.js

I want to be able to implement more rows or columns to the grid depending on the format. (For example if i want to use the sketch on a horizontal 16x9 screen, there would have to be more rows than columns) Right now it only works if the format/canvas is square.

As soon as I change the number of tiles or the size of the canvas, the elements jump around.
Here is my sketch:

```js
let colors = [
  "#F7F7F7",
  "#141414",
  "#FB2576",
  "#F48668",
  "#67339E",
  "#00A6A6",
  "#78FFD6"
];

function drawSubdividedCircle(x, y, size, segments, layers) {
  segments = random (1,13);
  layers = random (1,13);
  const r = 360 / segments;

  for (let i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < layers; j++) {
      fill(random(colors));
      const s = map(j, 0, layers, size, 0);
      arc(
        x + size / 2,
        y + size / 2,
        s,
        s,
        radians(r * i),
        radians(r * (i + 1)));
    }
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  frameRate(2);
}

function draw() {
  noStroke();

  let tilesX = 5;
  let tilesY = 5;
  let tileW = width / tilesX;
  let tileH = height / tilesY;
  const tileSize = width / tilesX;
  
  for (let x = 0; x < tilesX; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < tilesY; y++) {
      
  rect(x*tileW, y*tileH, tileW, tileH);
  fill(random(colors));
  
  push();
  for (let x = 0; x < tilesX; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < tilesY; y++) {
      
  let r = random(1);
  if (r < 0.5) {
    ellipseMode(CORNER);
    ellipse(x*tileW, y*tileH, tileW, tileH);
    fill(random(colors));
       } else {
        ellipseMode(CENTER);
        drawSubdividedCircle(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize);
        fill(random(colors));
  pop();
          }
        }  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little.. Removed two redundant for-loops, it is much faster now.
When you want to make your program responsive, you have to make a choice. Do you want the circles to scale when you change the resolution or maybe do you want the amount of rows/columns to change when the resolution changes? There are several possibilities, I made it now to keep the amount of tiles, and use the smaller value of the 'tileW' and 'tileH' to remain the circle shape.

```js
let colors = [
  "#F7F7F7",
  "#141414",
  "#FB2576",
  "#F48668",
  "#67339E",
  "#00A6A6",
  "#78FFD6"
];

var tilesX = 5;
var tilesY = 5;

var tileW;
var tileH;
var tileSize;

function drawSubdividedCircle(x, y, size, segments, layers)
{
  segments = random (1,13);
  layers = random (1,13);
  
  const r = 360 / segments;

  for (let i = 0; i < segments; i++)
  {
    for (let j = 0; j < layers; j++)
    {
      fill(random(colors));
      const s = map(j, 0, layers, size, 0);
      arc(
        x + size / 2,
        y + size / 2,
        s,
        s,
        radians(r * i),
        radians(r * (i + 1)));
    }
  }
}

function setup()
{
  createCanvas(550, 500);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  //frameRate(2);
  
  tileW    = width / tilesX;
  tileH    = height / tilesY;
  tileSize = min(tileW, tileH);
}

function draw()
{
  background(0);
  noStroke();

  for (let x = 0; x < tilesX; x++)
  {
    for (let y = 0; y < tilesY; y++)
    {
      rect(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
      fill(random(colors));

      let r = random(1);

      if (r < 0.5)
      {
        ellipse((x - 0.5) * tileSize, (y - 0.5) * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
        fill(random(colors));
      }
      else
      {
        drawSubdividedCircle(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize);
        fill(random(colors));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If thats possible I would want the amount of rows/columns to change according to the resolution. The tiles should always be square 1x1

Comment: @Johanna I made some example here: https://editor.p5js.org/Kroepniek/sketches/5FivRQ15O
Be careful with the tileSize setting. Setting it too small, will result in a very low framerate.